# Does the idea of "some" or "better" evidence for something make sense?

Tags: applied-philosophy, evidence

What does it mean to say that there's more evidence for A than there is for B? Or for there to be some evidence for A but not enough? Shouldn't evidence either be enough or not? Any standard you use for this is bound to result in axioms that may not be provable. As such, does it even make sense to talk about different grades of evidence?

In certain contexts, this may seem obviously useful. For example, if I am testing whether a coin is unbiased, clearly tossing it 10000 times instead of 4 times and getting about a 50/50 distribution of heads and tails seems to be better evidence for it being fair. However, I would argue that this is only because the experiment is the same in both bases and one experiment is included within another, with the only difference being the number of tosses.

But what about comparing different kinds of experiments?

Comment: Lot of questions. Can you pick one?

Comment: Why should it be only about experiments? I'm sure historians would say that there are all kinds of propositions about historical persons and events such that there is some evidence that a given proposition is true, or better evidence for this proposition than that one.

Comment: You notice your wife is spending extra time at work after she goes out of her way to be presentable.  Circumstantial evidence with reasonable doubt. You catch your wife in flagrante delicto. Irrefutable evidence beyond all doubt. Evidence is what persuades and some things are more persuasive than others.

Comment: Some of your questions are better than others :-)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your headline question is so trivially yes that I fear I might be overlooking some subtlety you have in your mind that has not quite managed to penetrate the barrier of stupidity that surrounds mine. Let me give you two examples...

Suppose I am your long-standing GP, and you come to my dilapidated and overcrowded premises with a complaint you are able to describe only in the vaguest terms. Being a seasoned medic, I have a hunch that what you are describing is the result of gallstones, but there could be other conditions that I must rule out. I do that by gathering 'better' evidence. I quiz you about correlations between the discomfort you have experienced and the nature of the meals you have eaten beforehand. I note that you are somewhat obese. My probing questions gradually reveal more evidence to support my supposition, my credence in which peaks when I send you for an ultrasound scan which shows definite granular patterns in the region of your gallbladder.

My second example is one from personal experience. Many years ago I made the mistake of buying an oil-fired 'Rayburn' which was designed to be both a cooking appliance and a central heating boiler, but proved to perform neither function well, owing to the compromises that had to be made to allow it to perform both. Whenever the Rayburn broke down, which it did with remarkable frequency, the engineers who serviced it had the philosophy that the best way, from their perspective at least, to identify the root cause was to replace a series of expensive parts at random until they cured the problem. Since I was funding these experiments, I eventually sacked them. Thereafter, whenever the hopeless appliance failed, I performed a series of diagnostic tests myself which gradually provided better and better evidence to pinpoint which of the countless design shortcomings in the device was to blame for its inability to heat my house.

I am sure that with more time I could bore you to death with countless other examples (better evidence, you might say) to show that it does make sense to talk about the amount and quality of evidence to support a particular conclusion.

Comment: Had the same problem with an of 80 percent 30k btu unit and the repair company.  Wound up with inferior parts I had to swap back out bc they were experimenting with after I figured out how to disassemble and resemble it myself.

Comment: This makes sense but I think this fits with the example I gave. When investigating for the same cause, or keeping the experiment the same, you can get better evidence. Doing one more coin toss to check if the coin is fair is trivially better. The question was moreso regarding different scenarios: for example whether tossing a coin 10 times is better evidence of the coin being fair than my answers to your probing questions being evidence for gallstones.

Comment: @thinkingman understood. I will need to cogitate on that puzzler!

Comment: @JD I've been there!